# Getting an Kubernetes Ingress endpoint/IP address

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

```
Base OS : CentOS (1 master 2 minions)
K8S version : 1.9.5 (deployed using KubeSpray)
```

I am new to Kubernetes Ingress and am setting up 2 different services, each reachable with its own path.

I have created 2 deployments :

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80
kubectl run echoserver --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080
```

I have also created their corresponding services :

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx --target-port=80 --type=NodePort
kubectl expose deployment echoserver --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort
```

My `svc` are :

```
[root@node1 kubernetes]# kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
echoserver   NodePort   10.233.48.121   <none>        8080:31250/TCP   47m
nginx        NodePort   10.233.44.54    <none>        80:32018/TCP     1h
```

My NodeIP address is `172.16.16.2` and I can access both pods using

```
http://172.16.16.2:31250 &
http://172.16.16.2:32018
```

Now on top of this I want to deploy an Ingress so that I can reach both pods not using 2 IPs and 2 different ports BUT 1 IP address with different paths.

So my Ingress file is :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /echo
        backend:
          serviceName: echoserver
          servicePort: 8080
```

This yields :

```
[root@node1 kubernetes]# kubectl describe  ing fanout-nginx-ingress
Name:             fanout-nginx-ingress
Namespace:        development
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     
        /nginx   nginx:80 (<none>)
        /echo    echoserver:8080 (<none>)
Annotations:
Events:  <none>
```

Now when I try accessing the Pods using the NodeIP address (172.16.16.2), I get nothing.

```
http://172.16.16.2/echo
http://172.16.16.2/nginx
```

Is there something I have missed in my configs ?

Comment: I am a kubernetes noob so take this with a grain of salt.  I noticed that the ingress is missing the "Address."  Could this be the issue?

Comment: You are right. It was missing.

Comment: how did you fix missing address. i have same problem. controller and app in same namesapce.. i catn acces them

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue on my bare metal installation - or rather something close to that (kubernetes virtual cluster - set of virtual machines connected via Host-Only-Adapter). Here is link to my [kubernetes vlab](https://github.com/ldynia/vagrant-k8s-centos).

First of all make sure that you have ingress controller installed. Currently there are two ingress controller worth trying [kubernetes nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) and [nginx kubernetes ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) -I installed first one.

#### Installation

Go to [installation instructions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) and execute first step

```
# prerequisite-generic-deployment-command
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml
```

Next get IP addresses of cluster nodes.

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME     STATUS   ROLES    ...   INTERNAL-IP    
master   Ready    master   ...   192.168.121.110
node01   Ready    <none>   ...   192.168.121.111
node02   Ready    <none>   ...   192.168.121.112
```

Further, crate `ingress-nginx` service of type `LoadBalancer`. I do it by downloading `NodePort` template service from installation tutorial and making following adjustments in `svc-ingress-nginx-lb.yaml` file.

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml > svc-ingress-nginx-lb.yaml

# my changes svc-ingress-nginx-lb.yaml
type: LoadBalancer
externalIPs:
  - 192.168.121.110
  - 192.168.121.111
  - 192.168.121.112
externalTrafficPolicy: Local

# create ingress- service
$ kubectl apply -f svc-ingress-nginx-lb.yaml
```

#### Verification

Check that `ingress-nginx` service was created.

```
$ kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                                                       PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.110.127.9   192.168.121.110,192.168.121.111,192.168.121.112   80:30284/TCP,443:31684/TCP   70m
```

Check that `nginx-ingress-controller` deployment was created.

```
$ kubectl get deploy -n ingress-nginx
NAME                       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-ingress-controller   1         1         1            1           73m
```

Check that `nginx-ingress` pod is running.

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -l 

app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller-5cd796c58c-lg6d4   1/1     Running   0          75m
```

Finally, check ingress controller version. **Don't forget to change pod name!**

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-5cd796c58c-lg6d4 -n ingress-nginx -- /nginx-ingress-controller --version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:    0.21.0
  Build:      git-b65b85cd9
  Repository: https://github.com/aledbf/ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Testing

Test that ingress controller is working by executing steps in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@Oskarr3/setting-up-ingress-on-minikube-6ae825e98f82) -of course, you will omit `minikube` part.

Successful, execution of all steps will create ingress controler resource that should look like this.

```
$ kubectl get ing
NAME               HOSTS                                ADDRESS                                          PORTS    AGE
ingress-tutorial   myminikube.info,cheeses.all          192.168.121.110,192.168.121.111,192.168.121.112   80      91m
```

And pods that looks like this.

```
$ kubectl get pods 
NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
cheddar-cheese-6f94c9dbfd-cll4z   1/1     Running            0          110m
echoserver-55dcfbf8c6-dwl6s       1/1     Running            0          104m
stilton-cheese-5f6bbdd7dd-8s8bf   1/1     Running            0          110m
```

Finally, test that request to `myminikube.info` propagates via ingress load balancer.

```
$ curl myminikube.info
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=10.44.0.7
command=GET
real path=/
query=nil
request_version=1.1
request_uri=http://myminikube.info:8080/

SERVER VALUES:
server_version=nginx: 1.10.0 - lua: 10001

HEADERS RECEIVED:
accept=*/*
host=myminikube.info
user-agent=curl/7.29.0
x-forwarded-for=10.32.0.1
x-forwarded-host=myminikube.info
x-forwarded-port=80
x-forwarded-proto=http
x-original-uri=/
x-real-ip=10.32.0.1
x-request-id=b2fb3ee219507bfa12472c7d481d4b72
x-scheme=http
BODY:
```

It was a long journey to make ingress working on bear metal like environment.Thus, i will include relevant links that helped me along.

- [reproducable tutorial](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)
- [installation of minikube on ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/install-minikube-ubuntu/)
- [ingress I](https://medium.com/@cashisclay/kubernetes-ingress-82aa960f658e)
- [ingress II](https://medium.com/@Oskarr3/setting-up-ingress-on-minikube-6ae825e98f82)
- [digging](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1750)
- [reverse engineering on ingress in kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/tree/master/deploy/addons/ingress)

Comment: I have managed to get it working by updating `svc-ingress-nginx-lb.yaml`. However the machines in the host network can only access one of the `EXTERNAL-IP`. Do you mind explaining how it works?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I did not set hostname for the ingress, so it is accessed directly through `EXTERNAL-IP `.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have an ingress controller in your cluster:

```
$ kubectl get po --all-namespaces
```

You should see something like:

```
kube-system nginx-ingress-controller-gwts0   1/1  Running   0    18d
```

It's only possible to create an ingress to address services inside the namespace in which the Ingress resides.
Cross-namespace ingresses are not implemented for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue (Ingress noob here). I deployed the Ingress controller using the following steps (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/deploy). I have one question only. Does the Ingress controller and the apps I want controlled by the Ingress controller have to be in the same name space ?

Comment: I added the reply to your question inside my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your cluster is missing Ingress controller.

In general, Ingress controller works as follows:
1. search for a certain type of objects (ingress,"nginx") in a cluster
2. parse that object and create configuration section for a specific ingress pod.
3. update that pod object (restart it with updated configuration)

That particular pod is responsible for processing traffic from incoming ports (usually a couple of dedicated ports on nodes) to configured traffic destination in cluster.

You can choose from two supported and maintained controllers - [Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md) and [GCE](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md)

The ingress controller consists of several components that you create during installation.
Here is installation part from [Nginx Ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md) documentation:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/namespace.yaml              | kubectl apply -f -
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/default-backend.yaml        | kubectl apply -f -
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/configmap.yaml              | kubectl apply -f -
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/tcp-services-configmap.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/udp-services-configmap.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

If you have [RBAC](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/rbac.md) authorization configured in your cluster:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/rbac.yaml      | kubectl apply -f -
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/with-rbac.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

If no RBAC configured:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/without-rbac.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

In case you create cluster from scratch:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Verify your installation:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -l app=ingress-nginx --watch
```

You should see something like:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller-699cdf846-nj2rw   1/1       Running   0          1h
```

Check available services and their parameters:

```
kubectl get services --all-namespaces
```

If you are using custom service provider deployment (minikube, AWS, Azure, GKE), follow [Nginx Ingress documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md#custom-service-provider-deployment) for installation details.

See official [Kubernetes Ingress documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) for details about Ingress.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I have done now and have a Ingress controller in a `ingress-nginx` namespace. But I deployed my app and its services in a different namespace. Turns out I cant do that. So Ill now redeploy its services and pods in the namespace `ingress-nginx` and see how it goes.

Comment: You don't have to put all your services in the ingress-controller namespace. You only need to have Ingress object to be in the same namespace with mentioned Service. Ingress object could be in any namespace, ingress-controller has permissions to read that kind of object from any namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I was using microk8s default nginx ingress controller on a later version of k8s (> 1.18) and I noticed this specific annotation was causing me an issue:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

It's present in a lot of older documentation and examples but it's apparently deprecated (see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)  and I had also defined an ingressClassName of "public" using the newer annotation. I'm not sure if it was the conflict between the two that caused the issue but once I removed the deprecated annotation my address appeared.

Answer (score 0):

1. For working your ingress resources **(fanout-nginx-ingress)**, you need to first deploy the ingress controller which is by-default not come in your local kubernetes cluster. You need to deploy it yourself.
2. There are many solution out there and you can use any of them, but nginx ingress controller is fine.
3. For detail information you can refer a great video on ingress by Mumshad Mannambeth here:
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhZi4DxaxxE

Comment: Better to sumarize what is inside the video than pointing to a video that may become unavailable someday.